# throwing an eslint error if disabling a rule that is not triggered

Tags: eslint

Is there an eslint rule that can throw an if you disable a rule that is not triggering an error in the line/file.

For instance, using `/* eslint-disable no-console */` would throw an error if used in a file that is not using console.

Does such rule exist already? I'm heavily using eslint in a React project and there seems that there could be many practical uses for such a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no rule to do so on the base eslint rules.

You could create one for yourself or add a plugin that adds this functionality, like:

[eslint-plugin-eslint-comments](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-eslint-comments)

Rule: https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-eslint-comments/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unused-disable.md

Answer (score 0):

ESLint has a command line flag `--report-unused-disable-directives` for this purpose.

See docs for details:
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#--report-unused-disable-directives

If you want to use a plugin, then [eslint-plugin-eslint-comments](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-eslint-comments) as mentioned by @Wayrex is a good option.